# How to make Singleton a Lazy instantiated class?

Tags: c#, singleton, lazy-evaluation

I have a class which is lazy instantiated by another library. I don't have control over that library code but still need to be sure it cannot create more than one instance of my class.

Is it possible ? how ?

Comment: Does that library instantiate "said" class?

Comment: I use `Lazy<myClass> hisClass;` so when `hisClass.Value` is accessed default constructor of my class is called. Although `Lazy` would return the same instance on next access tp `hisClass.Value` but I want to make sure nobody can create multiple instances of `myClass`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some simple solutions to this question hides some problems, for a full understanding of this matter I recommend the reading of the following article

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html

Which concludes with an optimal solution

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return Nested.instance;
        }
    }

    class Nested
    {
        // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
        // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
        static Nested()
        {
        }

        internal static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have read that article. It's about possible implementations of `Singleton` pattern with `C#` and do nothing with `Lazy` instantiation problem. The problem is caller doesn't access my class via `Instance` property. I have to do something in constructor. That's all I have.

Comment: @Xaqron OIC. You'll need a proxy class, which can be instantiated multiple times, and implements the same interface as your class. Then this proxy class calls the singleton methods.

Comment: +1 Just for the simple fact you pointed to a web page that talks about Java's Double Checked Locking being broken.

Answer (score 1):

If it's calling your class's constructor, the only thing you can do is throw an exception in the constructor if you determine that an instance was previously created. Since you don't have control over the other library, you wouldn't be able to use a factory method or static property which would normally be the way you control access to a singleton.

Depending on your situation, you may also look into using a lightweight proxy that wraps a singleton instance. In this example, any number of MyObjectProxy can be created but they all defer their implementation to a single instance of MyObject.

```
public class MyObject {

    internal MyObject() {
    }

    private int _counter;

    public int Increment() {
        return Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter);
    }

}

public class MyObjectProxy {

    private static readonly MyObject _singleton = new MyObject();

    public MyObjectProxy() {
    }

    public int Increment() {
        return _singleton.Increment();
    }

}
```

Comment: And where `MyObjectProxy` returns `MyObject` ?

Comment: In my example, MyObjectProxy doesn't return MyObject - It simply delegates its calls to the underling MyObject which is a singleton. Callers can create as many MyObjectProxy instances as they want but they'll always be incrementing the same counter.

Comment: That's good, we have one instance now, but that library is gonna do something with `myClass` which implements `ICallerLibraryInterface`. This way I got a bigger problem since `MyObjectProxy` doesn't work with that library.